# Write to a external file a Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame'

Tags: r, dataframe, list, data.table

A program that I am using in R generates an output of `Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame'`

And looks like this:

```
str(maytable)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  106876 obs. of  17 variables:
$ col1  : num  1 2 3 4  ...
$ col2  : chr  "Chr00c00001" "Chr00c00001" "Chr00c00001" "Chr00c00001" ...
$ col3  : num  1 2 3 4 ...
$ col4 :List of 106876
..$ : chr
..$ : chr
..$ : chr 
..$ : chr "Chr1g00005011"
.. [list output truncated]
$col4 :List of 106876
..$ : chr "Chr1g00000491"
..$ : chr
..$ : chr
..$ : chr "Chr1g00000501"
.. [list output truncated]
```

I would like to write this to a table where each col is a column and the data on them are in the rows to have something like this using functions like write.table

```
col1    col2      col3       col4       col5
  1  Chr00c00001   1                   Chr1g00000491
  2  Chr00c00001   2
  3  Chr00c00001   3
  4  Chr00c00001   4    Chr1g00005011  Chr1g00000501
```

I am not familiar with an object of classes data.table and data.frame that apparently contains lists and some other lists inside the elements of the list. It would be great if someone could advise me on what kind of object I have and how to convert it into a format I can write into a text file.

Answer (score 1):

It's a notion of either (or both) "list-columns" and/or "nested data". It's relatively useful for many things but at the same time many functions that work great on non-nested `data.frame`-like objects do not know how to work with list-columns/nested data. This is for a reasonable reason: simple (non-list) columns are clearly just vectors, so anything that works on a vector works on a column of a frame. However, with list-columns, as long as the length of the list is the same as the number of rows in the frame, you can put *anything* into each element of that list-column. This includes `NULL`, arbitrary-length vectors, graphic-objects (grobs), other `data.frame`-like objects, arbitrarily-nested lists, etc.

In your case, though, it looks like your list-columns are length 0 or 1 vectors. The typical unnesting of this data might remove the rows with length-0, so we need to take a little care by replacing empty-elements with something reasonable, whether `NA` or an empty string (since your list-columns appear to be string-based).

I think your data looks similar to this:

```r
obj <- data.table(col1=1:4, col2="c001", col3=11:14, col4=list(NULL, NULL, NULL, "5011"), col5=list("491", NULL, NULL, "501"))
obj
#     col1   col2  col3   col4   col5
#    <int> <char> <int> <list> <list>
# 1:     1   c001    11           491
# 2:     2   c001    12              
# 3:     3   c001    13              
# 4:     4   c001    14   5011    501
Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':  4 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ col1: int  1 2 3 4
 $ col2: chr  "c001" "c001" "c001" "c001"
 $ col3: int  11 12 13 14
 $ col4:List of 4
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr "5011"
 $ col5:List of 4
  ..$ : chr "491"
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr "501"
```

I recognize that this sample explicitly shows `NULL` whereas yours does not. This changes nothing: if your data has `""` instead of `NULL`, then my "guard against length 0" step will do no harm.

I think it's a safe thing first to confirm that what we have will reduce *simply*. That is, if any of the elements are length-0 (as I mentioned above), we need to make them length-1 with some sentinel value of emptiness. If any element is length 2 or more, though, it would suggest that that row would need to be repeated per that length. If this is known and desired behavior, then all is good; if not, you need to think about how to aggregate/reduce the data, e.g., `min`, `mean`, *first*, *last*, or *sample*.

Another note: you have two (or more) list-columns. The solution becomes a lot murkier if you have length > 1 in one list-column and a different length in another list-column. If they are both the same length, then we may be good with the assumption that two list-columns with length-n elements in the same rows should expand the same number of rows. However, if they are both length > 1 but different lengths, then ... do we do a cartesian expansion? Truncation? Lots of ways this can go wrong.  (I won't "fix" this condition here.)

For now, I'll assume:

- length 0 elements should be `NA` (actually `NA_character_`);
- length 2+ elements should expand the number of rows.

Again, if your data are all length-1 vectors then this will do no harm.

```r
obj[, (islist) := lapply(.SD, function(z) replace(z, !sapply(z, length), NA)), .SDcols = islist]
#     col1   col2  col3   col4   col5
#    <int> <char> <int> <list> <list>
# 1:     1   c001    11     NA    491
# 2:     2   c001    12     NA     NA
# 3:     3   c001    13     NA     NA
# 4:     4   c001    14   5011    501
```

From here, we can use `tidyr::unnest`:

```r
tidyr::unnest(obj, c(col4, col5))
# # A tibble: 4 × 5
#    col1 col2   col3 col4  col5 
#   <int> <chr> <int> <chr> <chr>
# 1     1 c001     11 <NA>  491  
# 2     2 c001     12 <NA>  <NA> 
# 3     3 c001     13 <NA>  <NA> 
# 4     4 c001     14 5011  501
```

Notice that this converted it from class `data.table` to class `tbl_df`; if you intend to continue using the `data.table` dialect of working on frames, then you'll need either `as.data.table` or `setDT` here.